# How to Fix: TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: react-native

Im making a little app and connecting it with an API to retrieve some info and show it. I had seen a way of doing it in a class and wanted to try it out, but it keeps giving the following error: "TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function".

I did make the page in App.js, which I'm not sure might be a problem or not, since I wasnt sure how to load a component/screen on launch of the app. I changed the `export default function App()` to `class App extends React.component` to be able to use a state to save the data from the api.

I already tried changing `export class ShowCustomerOrders extends React.Component` to `export class ShowCustomerOrders extends Component`. But the result doesn't change.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import MapScreen from './components/MapScreen';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'; 
import { FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class App extends React.component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      orders: []
    };
  }

  render(){
    getOrders();
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image style={styles.Map} source={{
              uri: 'https://open.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v5/map?center=eindhoven,5611DE,kerkstraat+7&locations=eindhoven,5611DE,kerkstraat+7|marker-md-FF0000-M&size=@2x&key=lYrP4vF3Uk5zgTiGGuEzQGwGIVDGuy24'
          }}/>
          <FlatList data={this.state.orders}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <ShowCustomerOrders navigation={this.props.navigation} order={item}/>}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function Map(){
  return(
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Map" component={MapScreen}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

getOrders = async() =>{
  const response = 
    await fetch('https://api.summa.1ku.nl/mad/oefenexamen/');
  const data = await response.json();

  this.setState({
      orders: data.orders
  });
}

export class ShowCustomerOrders extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.Navigation.navigate('Map', {order:this.props.order})}>
        <Text> {this.props.order.naam} </Text>
        <Text> {this.props.order.adres} </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  Map: {
    width: '80%',
    height: '40%',
    bottom: '20%'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with hooks...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import MapScreen from './components/MapScreen';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function ShowCustomerOrders(props) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Map', { order: props.order })}>
      <Text>{props.order.naam}</Text>
      <Text>{props.order.adres}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

function OrdersScreen(props) {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getOrders();
  }, []);

  const getOrders = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.summa.1ku.nl/mad/oefenexamen/');
    const data = await response.json();

    setOrders(data.orders);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        style={styles.Map}
        source={{
          uri:
            'https://open.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v5/map?center=eindhoven,5611DE,kerkstraat+7&locations=eindhoven,5611DE,kerkstraat+7|marker-md-FF0000-M&size=@2x&key=lYrP4vF3Uk5zgTiGGuEzQGwGIVDGuy24',
        }}
      />
      <FlatList
        data={orders}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ShowCustomerOrders navigation={props.navigation} order={item} />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Orders" component={OrdersScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Map" component={MapScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  Map: {
    width: '80%',
    height: '40%',
    bottom: '20%',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed several mistakes in your code.

1) You must pass `props` to the `constructor`.

2) In this `class` method, you need to call a function with `this` reference.

3) In `ShowCustomerOrders` component, you must write the contractor with props in order to use `props`.

4) There was no `default export` in `App.js`

Here is the code I edited. You can check if it works.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import MapScreen from './components/MapScreen';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'; 
import { FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default class App extends React.component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      orders: []
    };
  }

  getOrders = async() =>{
    const response = 
      await fetch('https://api.summa.1ku.nl/mad/oefenexamen/');
    const data = await response.json();

    this.setState({
        orders: data.orders
    });
  }

  render(){
    this.getOrders();

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.Map} source={{
                uri: 'https://open.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v5/map?center=eindhoven,5611DE,kerkstraat+7&locations=eindhoven,5611DE,kerkstraat+7|marker-md-FF0000-M&size=@2x&key=lYrP4vF3Uk5zgTiGGuEzQGwGIVDGuy24'
            }}/>
            <FlatList data={this.state.orders}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <ShowCustomerOrders navigation={this.props.navigation} order={item}/>}/>
        </View>
      );
    }
}

function Map(){
  return(
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Map" component={MapScreen}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}



export class ShowCustomerOrders extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.Navigation.navigate('Map', {order:this.props.order})}>
        <Text> {this.props.order.naam} </Text>
        <Text> {this.props.order.adres} </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  Map: {
    width: '80%',
    height: '40%',
    bottom: '20%'
  }
});
```

I recommend you to work with `hooks` (uses `function` instead of a `class`) since it has a lot of advantages. With that method also, you can use `states` without any problem.

Comment: I've made all the changes you noted, but they dont seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Yes I am, and I went over every piece of your list and applied the change

Comment: Shall I update the code with hooks? Then you can try it there. I'm pretty sure you can solve the problem there...

Comment: yes you can try, after that should I just copy + paste all of the code into mine?

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you for the effort. Even though I dont fully understand how the hooks work.

Comment: You are welcome :-) If it worked and if you prefer, you can mark the answer as the correct answer... :-) BTW, Please refer https://medium.com/crowdbotics/build-a-react-native-app-with-react-hooks-5498e1d5fdf6 to understand about hooks. Hooks are really nice when you are aware of how to use them... Good luck!

Comment: `useState` hook is used to handle `states`. `useEffect` hook is something like `componentDidMount` and that hook can be used in very useful manner.

Comment: aaah I see, we haven't gone over hooks so I had no idea